# How do I go set up an aspx web page, so an outsourcer can send me data?

Tags: asp.net

Need to setup a URL for data to be sent, as seen below. 
http://yourdomain/getdelivery.aspx?batchid=$batchid&mobile=$mobile&status=$status

Hello,

I googled but almost all the results were how to get the data and not how to set up the web page and set the domain. Me being a newbie both as a sysadmin and certainly with web development I got stuck. I ask for your help to set me in the correct course.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way is to add a web form page called `GetDelivery.aspx`.

In `GetDelivery.aspx` :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GetDelivery.aspx.cs" Inherits="PortalBmoTrsb.GetDelivery" %>
```

In `GetDelivery.aspx.cs` :

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public partial class GetDelivery : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var batchid = Request["batchid"];
            var mobile = Request["mobile"];
            var status = Request["status"];
        }
    }
}
```

You also should check a look to `Web Api Controller`.